# Check if value appears in combobox

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox, duplicates

I want to check if an item from my array appears in my combobox before adding that item to the combobox, to **avoid duplicates**.

**I AM NOT ALLOWED TO USE LINQ**

**Code:**

```
private void ToonCategorien()
    {
        cboCategorie.Items.Clear();
        foreach (String sCategorie in marrCategorie){
            if (!cboCategorie.Items.Contains(sCategorie))
            {
                ComboBoxItem cboItem = new ComboBoxItem();
                cboItem.Content = sCategorie;
                cboCategorie.Items.Add(cboItem);
            }
        }
    }
```

Sorry for using Dutch in my C# code.

So [marrCategorie](http://gyazo.com/850103815e6787b383fddc1a88a2ea08.png) is an array that contains all categories that I read from StreamReader.
The problem is that he adds everything anyway. I assume this is a problem in my if-loop.

I also tried *if(cboCategorie.Text.Contains(sCategorie))* with no result.

**I am not allowed to post pictures directly yet, so sorry for using a hyperlink):**

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2nAq.png)

Thanks in advance!

**Solution, thanks to Bolu:**

```
    private void ToonCategorien()
    {
        cboCategorie.Items.Clear();
        foreach (String sCategorie in marrCategorie){
            if (!cboCategorie.Items.Contains(sCategorie))
            {
                cboCategorie.Items.Add(sCategorie);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try putting the check in before you do `cboCategorie.Items.Add(cboItem);`
Like: `if(!cboCategorie.Items.Contains(cboItem))`

Comment: you are clearing items and then check if some item is there,like that all items will not be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are comparing `string` with `ComboBoxItem` here, I think you can just use string: e.g:

```
private void ToonCategorien()
    {
        cboCategorie.Items.Clear();
        foreach (String sCategorie in marrCategorie){
            if (!cboCategorie.Items.Contains(sCategorie))
            {                
                cboCategorie.Items.Add(sCategorie);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Woah, no idea why I actually used ComboBoxItem here.. Guess I was confused with some other projects on school. Thanks for clearing it out!